# Tkinter Text Widget Indexing

Tags: python, tkinter

I am building a simple calculator using Python and Tkinter.
On this calculator am using the Text widget as the screen.I have buttons with numbers and symbols, which, when pressed, insert a character onto the screen. The idea is that I take the contents of the screen as a string and pass them to eval().

How do I grab this contents of the screen? I've looked at indexing but it just doesn't seem to work.

```
def buttonCommand(mytext, sym):
   mytext.insert(END, sym)
   if sym == "=":
      return eval() #<-- something goes here?
```

Comment: The documentation shows a `get` method. Have you tried it?

Comment: Wow, ok, no. I am not using the manual. Just some books. It's hard to put together what some of these books are saying into actual, working code.

Comment: Your first step should _always_ be to read some documentation before asking a question. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def buttonCommand(mytext, sym):
   mytext.insert(END, sym)
   if sym == "=":
      return eval(mytext.get())
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not see that! I'm just starting out on this.